# iMac 27" Catalina with Split Fusion Drives

Tags: macos, partition, restore, repair

I need to have a clean iMac with new OS but experiencing problems.  Having commenced Recovery mode twice with new OS I am seeing Four drives.  One is the 1Tb SSD but the main primary drive is showing as iMac (121.12Gb) plus another two named as iMac2-Data and iMac2-Dat-Dat.  How to have just two drives, SSD plus primary drive?

Here is terminal screen image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First: it is normal with APFS to list the internal physical drives, followed by 'synthesized' volumes. So you should expect to see `/dev/disk0` to `3`.

Catalina uses two separate volumes for a system disk: `iMac2` is the read-only volume for your OS, and `iMac2 - Data` is for your apps, user data and everything else.

However, from the looks of it, `iMac2` is too small to hold an OS. It looks like you've installed the OS onto `iMac2 - Data`, and the OS has created a matching  'Data' partition called `iMac2 - Data - Data`.

I'd suggest erasing the entire device - you may need to check "Show All Devices" in the View menu in Disk Utility - and then install from scratch.

Comment: This is very helpful many thanks, however, now I've erased the volumes and when attempting to Recover (Command/R) it says looking at Internet and then shows  a big ? and refers to Apple Support.  So I have no way to proceed.  Would a bootable external drive be located by the Mac?  Whats is best way to proceed?